# How to join 2 files based on common rows of first columns?

Tags: shell, join, merge

```
file1 :

HOUSAM1189870            3      0.00   0  -2450.00  11
HOUSAM1213135            3      0.00   0  -2620.00   2
HOCANM245675             3      0.00   0      0.00   0
HOUSAM1239242            3      0.00   0  -3113.00   8

file2 :

AY840F3001138842 20050301
AY840F3001140253 20060101
HOCANM245675     34409887        
HOUSAM1239242    34444444
```

I want to join file1 and file2 based on common rows of their first column. therefore the output should be:

```
file3:

HOCANM245675             3      0.00   0      0.00   0 34409887
HOUSAM1239242            3      0.00   0  -3113.00   8 34444444
```

any suggestion, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(note: this answer was written before the question was updated with the `join` command and the error messages)

the command is called `join`.

from the man page:

> join - join lines of two files on a common field

since your input files are not sorted you need to sort them first

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

the `<(...)` things are called [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) and is supported by bash and some other shells. if you have a shell that does not support process substitution then you have to work with intermediate files.

`join` is part of the gnu coreutils so it should be installed on most common gnu/linux systems.

Comment: i tried it but it does nit work

Comment: does it help when you sort the files first? please explain how it does not work. please update the question with the relevant information.

Comment: problem is that when I use this command on my real data I have this error all the time :join: file 2 is not in sorted order
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
 do you know why is  that? I should not recive this error as I already sorted them

Comment: your first file is not sorted. i tried join with (sorted) files in your updated question and everything worked fine. perhaps the size of the files is the problem?